# Pandas pivot_table gives KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

(I'm fairly new to Python and completely new to Pandas.)

I have software usage data in a tab-separated txt file like this:

```
IP_Addr Date    Col2    Version Col4    Col5    Lang    Country
160.86.229.29   2021-11-01  00:00:14.919    9.6 337722669   3   ja  JPN
154.28.188.105  2021-11-01  00:00:19.774    9.7 480113424   3   de  DEU
154.6.16.129    2021-11-01  00:00:52.460    9.0 3278201755  2   en  USA
218.45.244.124  2021-11-01  00:01:33.853    9.7 1961440872  2   ja  JPN
178.248.141.33  2021-11-01  00:01:51.114    9.5 2795265301  2   en  EST
```

The DataFrame is imported correctly, and groupby methods like this work all right:

```
df.IP_Addr.groupby(df.Country).nunique()
```

However, when I'm trying to create a pivot table with this line:

```
country_and_lang = df.pivot_table(index=df.Country, columns=df.Lang, values=df.IP_Addr, aggfunc=df.IP_Addr.count)
```

I get

```
KeyError: '160.86.229.29'
```

where the "key" is the first IP value - which should not be used as a key at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use column names instead values:

```
country_and_lang = df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Lang', 
                                  values='IP_Addr', aggfunc='count')
print(country_and_lang)

# Output
Lang      de   en   ja
Country               
DEU      1.0  NaN  NaN
EST      NaN  1.0  NaN
JPN      NaN  NaN  2.0
USA      NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Or use `pd.crosstab`:

```
country_and_lang = pd.crosstab(df['Country'], df['Lang'], 
                               df['IP_Addr'], aggfunc='count')
print(country_and_lang)

# Output
Lang      de   en   ja
Country               
DEU      1.0  NaN  NaN
EST      NaN  1.0  NaN
JPN      NaN  NaN  2.0
USA      NaN  1.0  NaN
```